# General node.js/javascript question and event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, event-loop

I have following problem:
I let two functions write into my database. Before they get inserted into the database I check if a similar item exists:

```
const storeListing = async listing => {
   //Some logic
   const foundSimilar = await findSimilar(listing);
  if(!foundSimilar){
     await insertListing(listing)
  }else{
    //Perform duplicate check
    if(foundSimilar.buildingType===listing.buildingType){
       console.log('found')
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I do following:

```
const test = () => {
  storeListing({buildingType:'MFH'});
  storeListing({buildingType:'MFH'});
}
```

The else condition with the duplicate check is never triggered.

My idea would be that the two functions get handled sequentially (event loop). So storeListing can not be called again before one is done.

So do I have a logical issue here or is it just the database having eventual consistency?

---

Edit:
When I do not know how many other functions call storeListing and I want it to happen serialized (e.g. I have storeListing for Multi family house - store listing for single family house).

Is this a good pattern:

```
const lock={};
export const storeListing = async (listing, type) => {
  const id= uuidv1();

  while (Object.keys(lock).length>0){
    await timeout(15);
  }
  threadLock[id]=true;
  //Function like above

  delete lock[id];
}
```

Comment: your not `await`ing in test.

Comment: The order does not matter in this case - the items are similar. So if one is inserted number two will be similar and vice versa. I did just put a comment here - there is logic still in there but left it out to give a better overview ;) But I made the code now clearer :)

Comment: noice, it must just be the not awaiting..when ever you add async to a function your turning it into a promise, so the calling code must await.

Comment: This looks like a database race condition as you have two queries in flight at the same time and they won't be serialized.  When you call out  to native code interfaces (like a database), there's probably not any single thread, event loop-driven restrictions on that native code.  Can't program this way to native code interfaces.  You'd have to show us the actual code for `findSimilar()` for us to have an idea what to suggest, but you will generally need to concurrency management features of your database.

Comment: FYI, posting a question with only pseudo-code means we can't give you any concrete advice, only pseudo-advice.  The proper solution here depends upon the actual real code, what type of datastore you're using and what its interface is.  Please post real code when asking questions here.  You will get sooooo much more valuable advice and often much quicker without a lot of back and forth questions.

Comment: So it is rather a database issue then a logical issue. Can you check my edit if this is an okish pattern or if it is total nonsense

Comment: That's generally the wrong way to try to solve database concurrency problems. Databases have built-in concurrency features for problems like this that don't have all the limitations something like this would.  Plus, polling a lock is a really yuck design in an event-driven system.  You get a bunch of these locks pending and active and your CPU will spend a lot of its time just polling locks.  Not to mention that you have no "fair" system for who gets to go next as its random.  Can't use clustering.  Won't protect against other processes accessing the database and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the insertion order isn't relevant you still need to use `await` in order to avoid race conditions.

Your full code queues up the following I/O operations:

1. findSimilarOne
2. insertListingOne (if findSimilarOne returns no match)
3. findSimilarTwo
4. insertListingTwo (if findSimilarTwo returns no match)

The only restrictions on the ordering of these operations is that #1 must occur before #2, and #3 must occur before #4.

The order that these are completing in is: #1, #3, #2, #4

Because both `findSimilar` calls complete before either `insertListing` completes, they both return no match.

You should use `async`, like so:

```
let test = async () => {
  await storeListing({ buildingType:'MFH' });
  await storeListing({ buildingType:'MFH' });
};
```

This enforces a new restriction on the operation order: that #2 must occur before #3

Comment: ...or maybe `storeListing` is supposed to do transactions properly, and the bug is there. It's not clear to me from the question what the requirements are.

Comment: That's probably a better suggestion! I'd prefer to see the uniqueness of "buildingType" (or whatever constitues "similarity") enforced at the DB layer.

Comment: Ya I see my question is not sharp enough. Am sorry for that. But all of those suggestions already helped me